# Add function javascript to element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add the return of a function to an element in Jquery. For this I use :

```
function coloredInput(TrigColor) {

    if (TrigColor === "error") {
        TrigColor = $(this).css("border-color", "red").css("color", "red");
        return TrigColor;
    } else if (TrigColor === "pass") {
        TrigColor = $(this).css("border-color", "green").css("color", "green");
        return TrigColor;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

I Try as follow :

```
$("#test").on("click", function() {

      var test  = $("#test").val();
if(test == "") {
    $("#myInput").coloredInput("error");
           }
});
```

How can I make it work ?

**Question edited, the answer of this thread do not work.**

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ - have a look at jQuery plugins - that is what you need

Comment: There are several similar questions on SO but the ones I found are too bad for linking because Google is better at answering "How to make a jquery plugin ?"

Comment: To me this question is like sorting an unordered list with a shuffle algorithm. Learn some fundamentals before action.

Comment: Thanks for downvote and nice reply. I'm not looking by a plugin jquery but a function as my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a plugin, you could create your function like that

```
function coloredInput(TrigSelector, TrigColor) {

    if (TrigColor === "error") {
        $(TrigSelector).css("border-color", "red").css("color", "red");
    } else if (TrigColor === "pass") {
        $(TrigSelector).css("border-color", "green").css("color", "green");
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
coloredInput('#myInput', 'error');
```

Comment: Thank you devnull, it's what I'm looking for and not a plugin. 

Unfortunately, it's does not work, any idea ? I came up with that early too...

Comment: It works in this fiddle, so the problem must be somewhere else: http://jsfiddle.net/fzrpfeeo/

Comment: Read my first post I edited it I think it's because I try to make it work inside a jquery function...

Comment: You cannot call your function like this `$(selector).coloredInput(whatever)` because you'd need a plugin for that. Please call it like `coloredInput(selector, whatever)`

Answer (score 0):

First need to create a jQuery plugin
here is a link of [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

```
<script>

    $.fn.coloredInput = function(TrigColor) {

         if (TrigColor === "error") {
            TrigColor = this.css("border-color", "red").css("color", "red");
            return TrigColor;
        } else if (TrigColor === "pass") {
            TrigColor = this.css("border-color", "green").css("color", "green");
            return TrigColor;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

       $("#myInput").coloredInput("error");

    });


</script>
```